# Difference Between Scipy.optimize.least_squares and Scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two methods.

Both seem to be able to be used to find optimal parameters for an non-linear function using constraints and using least squares.

However, they are evidently not the same because `curve_fit` results do not correspond to a third solver whereas `least_squares` does.

Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no fundamental difference between  `curve_fit` and `least_squares`. Moreover, if you don't use `method = 'lm'`they do exactly the same thing. You can check it in a [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L511-L813) of `curve_fit` fucntion on a Github:

```
if method == 'lm':
    ...
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    ...
else:
   ...
    res = least_squares(func, p0, jac=jac, bounds=bounds, method=method,
                        **kwargs)
   ...
```

So, `curve_fit` is just a wrapper around `least_squares`. I've just checked them out and I've got the same results from both.